# Offline validation for xml using system xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

When we put the xsd in the xsi:schemaLocation, does it download the xsd from the internet and validate the xml?

I want to do an offline-validation by downloading the xsd if that is the case, How can I achieve this?

I know how to do offline-validation for DTD's but not sure about xsd.

For DTD's, I am currently doing the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config SYSTEM "struts-config_1_1.dtd">
```

Can I do something like this?

**From**

```
<!-- beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"-->
```

**to**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           file://spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           file://spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

EDIT:

Looks like I am wrong. The spring only goes to internet when there it doesn't find the dtd/xsd in the jar file. I pulled the internet plug and saw that the application works fine.

Also, source: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=949031

Sorry for the trouble and wrong question.

Comment: Does it download...? Who is "it"? Different software behaves differently. We can't tell you how your software behaves without knowing what "it" is.

Comment: @MichaelKay my bad, wrong question. It does download and it works fine offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can; what you need to make sure though is that the URI must be valid for your scheme (file:// in your case, which on Windows is more like file://c:/something/my.xsd).

Make sure that all the XSD files are stored locally as well, and all references between XSD files are correct.

Comment: Can I give a relative URI, file://my.xsd instead of absolute path ,  file://c:/something/my.xsd?

Comment: I wouldn't use file:// for relative; just ./my.xsd (don't use a scheme for relative, that's what I mean).